# Rebus polymorphic dispatch strange behavior

Tags: rebus

I'm having a strange problem with polymorphic message dispatch in Rebus 3.1.2 with MSMQ transport and StructureMap 4.4.2 container.

If I have a message:

```
public class SomeMessage
```

and some handlers:

```
public class Handler1 : IHandleMessages<SomeMessage>
public class Handler2 : IHandleMessages<SomeMessage>
```

When I send SomeMessage, both handlers fire as expected.

However, when I have a message:

```
public class SomeMessage : ISomeInterface
```

and some handlers:

```
public class Handler1 : IHandleMessages<SomeMessage>
public class Handler2 : IHandleMessages<ISomeInterface>
```

When I send SomeMessage, only Handler1 fires.  But if I comment out Handler1 and send the message again, Handler2 will fire.

The same is true if SomeMessage inherited from SomeBaseClass and Handler2 handled SomeBaseClass (or even object).  Only Handler1 will fire.  But if I comment out Handler1, Handler2 will fire.

It's almost like it doesn't attempt polymorphic dispatch if it finds any handlers for the specific message class.

Because Handler2 will fire when I comment out Handler1, I don't think it's a container issue.  I'm guessing if this was really broken, someone else would have noticed.  So I'm assuming it's me, but I don't know where to go from here.

AFAIK, there's nothing to configure about polymorphic dispatch, right?

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not an expert on SO guidelines, but shouldn't this have been a GitHub issue instead?

Comment: That was actually my first thought, but your [blog](http://mookid.dk/oncode/rebus) says to post Rebus questions here.  Would you like me to repost in GitHub?